# residuals for proportion prediction

Tags: regression, bayesian, residuals

There is something I am not sure about. If the random variable I'm modelling/predicitng is a 'proportion' (therefore between 0 and 1). So say $X \sim Beta(\alpha, \beta)$.

Now if I want to evaluate my model, do I evaluate it as any other Bayesian regression model (using Standardised Pearson residuals)? So I guess my question is if Standardised Pearson residuals are invariant to the range of the value that we are predicting (if say its between [0,1] or [-100,100])?

Comment: Ratios are not automatically between 0 and 1 (e.g. the ratio of male births to  female births is above 1). Do you mean to say that your observations are proportions between 0 and 1?

Comment: If your "ratios" are actually proportions, $z/N$, then you could/should model them as $z \sim binomial( \theta , N )$.

Comment: Hi. Yeah I meant proportion, sorry about the confusion (just fixed it). I can't however use a binomial distribution as I'm modelling water proportion in some material (so I really can't specify 'N')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gather that you're trying to predict the measurement $y \in [0,1]$ from some predictor, $x$. For example, predict water proportion as a function of, say, temperature. This is straight forward. One approach is as follows:

First, y is beta distributed around a trend specified by $\alpha$ and $\beta$:
$$y_i \sim \mbox{beta}( \alpha_i , \beta_i )$$

Re-parameterize $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in terms of the mode ($\omega$) and concentration ($\kappa$) of the beta distribution:
$$ \alpha_i = \omega_i (\kappa-2) + 1 \\
\beta_i = (1-\omega_i) (\kappa-2) + 1 $$
Notice above that $\kappa$ is assumed to be the same for all $i$, which is analogous to the usual assumption of homogeneity of variance.

Then make the mode, $\omega_i$, a logistic function of the predictor, $x_i$:
$$ \omega_i = \mbox{logistic}( \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i ) $$

Finally, put some sensible prior distribution on $\kappa$, $\beta_0$, and $\beta_1$.

In summary, the model says that the central tendency of $y$ is a logistic function of $x$. The central tendency is denoted $\omega$, and it's the mode of the beta-distributed $y$ values at $x$. The lack of noise around the central tendency is the concentration, $\kappa$.

This sort of re-parameterization of the beta distribution is discussed in Chapter 6 of [DBDA2E](https://sites.google.com/site/doingbayesiandataanalysis/) and then used repeatedly in many models throughout the rest of that book. It's straight forward to express the re-parameterization in JAGS. See, for example, p. 239 of [DBDA2E](https://sites.google.com/site/doingbayesiandataanalysis/).